# A special open cover?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\delta>0$. Can we find a finite open cover
$ \{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $K$ such that every $B_i$ is an open ball and the radius of $B_i$ is smaller than $\delta$ and if $B_i\cap B_j\neq\emptyset$, then $B_i\cap B_j\cap K\neq \emptyset.$

When $K$ is the boundary of a bounded domain, this is a technique for the
extension of function defined on the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a bit of an algorithmic proof:

First, take any finite open cover $\mathcal{B}_1=\{B_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $K$, where $B_i$ is a ball with radius $<\delta$. This is possible due to the compactness of $K$. Consider the subset $I_1 \subseteq I$ such that $B_i \subseteq K$ for all $i \in I_1$, i.e. if $i \in I_1$, then $B_i$ is contained in $K$. For these $B_i$ it is clear that $B_i \cap B_j \neq \emptyset \implies B_i \cap B_j \cap K \neq \emptyset$. Define $\mathcal{B}_2 := \{B_i\}_{i \in I_1} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_1$.

Next, find a finite open cover $\mathcal{B}' = \{B_j\}_{j \in J}$ of $\partial K$, where, again, the radius $r$ of each $B_j$ is $<\delta$ and each center of $B_j$ lies exactly on $\partial K$. Moreover, we choose $r$ to be small enough, so that $B_i \cap B_l$ is always empty if $B_j \cap \partial K$ and $B_l \cap \partial K$ are not path connected (here, $j,l \in J$). This way we separate the open covers of the different path components of $K$, which will save us some work later on, as we'll get fewer non-empty intersections to deal with.

So by the construction of $\mathcal{B}'$ we get that for any $B_j \cap B_l \neq \emptyset$, with $j,l\in J\implies B_j \cap B_l \cap K \neq \emptyset$.

The set $\mathcal{B}_2 \cup \mathcal{B}'$ almost gives us what we want. However, it is possible that the set $A=K \setminus (\mathcal{B}_2 \cup \mathcal{B}')$ is non-empty. But this is no problem, as $A$ has finite volume, so we find a collection of open balls $\mathcal{B}'' = \{B_j\}_{j\in J'}$ covering $A$, with the radius of each $B_j$ sufficiently small, so that $B_j \subseteq K$.

Now we are done, since $\mathfrak{B} := \mathcal{B}_2 \cup \mathcal{B}' \cup \mathcal{B}''$ is an open cover that satisfies what you need. $\mathfrak{B}$ is a finite cover, since $I_1 \cup J \cup J'$ is finite.

Even though this was quite messy, I hope it was helpful to you!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how can we construct such $\mathcal{B}'$.

Comment: $\partial K$ is closed and bounded, so compact, or am I missing something?

Comment: I say this "we choose $r$ to be small enough, so that $B_i \cap B_l$ is always empty if $B_j \cap \partial K$ and $B_l \cap \partial K$ are not path connected (here, $j,l \in J$)".

Comment: Why when then are not path connected,  the intersection is empty?

Comment: I meant to say that we choose $r$ so small that we force an empty intersection. Of course, if we hadn't modified our $r$, then it's certainly possible that the intersection is non-empty.

Comment: But why when $r$ is small enough, then the intersection is nonempty.